# Check sklearn version before loading model using joblib

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I've followed [this guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) to save a machine learning model for later use. The model was dumped in one machine:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, 'model.pkl')
```

And when I loaded it `joblib.load('model.pkl')` in another machine, I got this warning:

> UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator DecisionTreeClassifier from
> version pre-0.18 when using version 0.18.1. This might lead to
> breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.

So is there any way to know the sklearn version of the saved model to compare it with the current version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Versioning of pickled estimators [was added in scikit-learn 0.18](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7248). Starting from v0.18, you can get the version of scikit-learn used to create the estimator with,

```
estimator.__getstate__()['_sklearn_version']
```

The warning you get is produced by the [`__setstate__` method](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py#L298) of the estimator which is automatically called upon  unpickling. It doesn't look like there is a straightforward way of getting this version without loading the estimator from disk. You can filter out the warning, with,

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
      warnings.simplefilter("ignore", category=UserWarning)
      estimator = joblib.load('model.pkl')
```

For pre-0.18 versions, there is no such mechanism, but I imagine you could, for instance, use `not hasattr(estimator, '__getstate')` as a test to detect to, at least, `pre-0.18` versions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I filter out the warning by the way? Actually, the reason I want to get the version before loading the estimator is to get rid of this warning.

Comment: This doesn't work since after the model is loaded, `estimator.__getstate__()` will set `_sklearn_version` to the version of the currently loaded sklearn library. See [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/base.py#L316).

Answer (score -2):

I have the same problem, just re-training datasets and save again the 'model.pkl' file with joblib.dump. This will be resolved. Good luck!