# Is there a way to know which sklearn version was used to train a pickle model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I was given a pickle file with a trained gradient boosting model that was trained by someone else on another machine. I realised that I could not load this pickle file on my machine using

```
with open('gb_model.pickle','rb') as f:
    gbmodel = pickle.load(f)
```

My current version of `scikit-learn==0.24.2`. I got the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.ensemble.gradient_boosting'`. I then tried installing other versions of `sklearn` but I keep getting other errors related to `sklearn`. I also tried using `joblib` but get the same results:

```
from joblib import load
clf = load('gb_model.pickle')
```

I realised I need to load the pickled file with the same `sklearn` version this was installed with. [I saw here that one is able to check the version after loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146759/check-sklearn-version-before-loading-model-using-joblib), but it seems like I can't even load the pickle file. Is there another way of doing this? I want to end up being able to load the pickled model. According to [official documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#interoperable-formats), ideally there should be metadata saved along the pickled model, but I was not provided this, is there a way to obtain this from the pickle file alone?

Answer (score 2):

If you trained the model with sklearn version 0.18 or higher, then try:

```py
import pickle
clf = pickle.load(open('gb_model.pickle', 'rb'))
clf.__getstate__()['_sklearn_version']
```

However, there is literally no module called `gradient_boosting` inside `sklearn.ensemble`, which is what's causing the problem. The closest module would be `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier`, or [this module](https://www.openml.org/f/9667) from OpenML (which I had never heard of).

Comment: This doesn't work since after the model is loaded, `clf.__getstate__()` will set `_sklearn_version` to the version of the currently loaded sklearn library. See [the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913be6d7e485b792ea36e9268be31ed52d0/sklearn/base.py#L316).